# Add class to custom jQuery accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just needed a simple accordion script and didn't want to deal with the bloat of the jQuery accordion widget and found this one online. It works just fine but I would like to know if I can add a class like `active` to an opened accordion block.

Here is the script:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {

    //Expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

    //Hide the other panels
    $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

  });
});
```

```css
.accordion-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-content {
  display: none;
}

.accordion-content.default {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 1</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content default">
    <p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 2</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet mauris eu turpis.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 3</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, like in this code (using `.addClass` method)

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {

    //Expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).next().addClass('active').slideToggle('fast');

    //Hide the other panels
    $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).removeClass('active').slideUp('fast');

  });
});
```

```css
.accordion-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-content {
  display: none;
}

.accordion-content.default {
  display: block;
}

/* just to demo the .active class */
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 1</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content default active">
    <p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 2</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet mauris eu turpis.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 3</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I styled to `.active` with `background: red` to display the effect of `.active`

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks!  I wasn't sure if I could use addClass on the .next since it was for expanding and collapsing.

Comment: One more question:  is there a way to target h4 for adding the active class versus the div?

Comment: Sure. The great thing about jQuery that once you "wrapped" an element with jQuery (e.g. `$`), you can run on it all the method you have on jQuery. If you are not sure what is the current jQuery object, just `log` it, and you will see. I strongly recommend to read the [docs of jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/).